# Swiftmailer destinatarios mysql

Tags: php, mysql, email, swiftmailer

I need to send multiple emails stored in a mysql database with phpmailer, but when I want to execute it it returns a 500 page error, I understand that the problem is when I enter the data inside:

```
->setTo(["'".$row['email']."'" => "'".$row['nombre']."'"])
```

I clarify that everything works perfect, only that when I enter any type of variable or call to the db within the:
    -> setTo (["'". $ row [' email ']. "'" => "'". $ row [' name ']. 
    "'"])
It returns an error.
This is my complete code:

```
<?php 
include ('../db.php');
$query =$db->query("SELECT id, email, status, nombre, enviados FROM 
contactos WHERE email='example@gmail.com' OR 
email='example@icloud.com'");
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
// Create the Transport
$transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.hostinger.com.ar', 
587))
->setUsername('example@example.com')
->setPassword('example')
   ;

 // Create the Mailer using your created Transport
 $mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

 // Create a message
 $message = (new Swift_Message('msm'))
  ->setFrom(['example@example.com' => 'John Doe'])

 $datos_seleccionados = [];
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
  {
   ->setTo(["'".$row['email']."'" => "'".$row['nombre']."'"])

   }
   ->setBody('INTENTO')
   ;
   // Send the message
   $result = $mailer->send($message);
```

What I need is for me to take multiple recipients stored in my database

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: Also, none of the extra quotes in the line you quoted are needed. `>setTo([$row['email'] =>$row['nombre']])` is fine

Comment: `->setTo` is not valid syntax - you need an object instance before the `->` to be able to call an object method. This should probably simply be `$message->setTo(…)`, and of course the same thing for setBody. You should go read up on some syntax basics - inventing your own usually doesn’t get you very far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
include ('../db.php');
$query =$db->query("SELECT id, email, status, nombre, enviados FROM 
contactos WHERE email='example@gmail.com' OR 
email='example@icloud.com'");
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
// Create the Transport
$transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.hostinger.com.ar', 
587))
->setUsername('example@example.com')
->setPassword('example')
   ;

 // Create the Mailer using your created Transport
 $mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);



 $datos_seleccionados = [];
$toEmailList=[];
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
  {
    $toEmailList[$row['email']]=$row['nombre'];

   }
 // Create a message
 $message = (new Swift_Message('msm'))->setFrom(['example@example.com' => 'John Doe'])->setTo($toEmailList)->setBody('INTENTO');
   // Send the message
   $result = $mailer->send($message);
```

Problem with your code is you are trying to concat key and value.
You have to call all the function at once.
Thanks

Comment: Please explain what you've changed and why, such that others can learn from your answer

Comment: [22-May-2019 15:08:46 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE) in /home/u257235474/domains/flapeer.com/public_html/emailsempresas/email/email2.php on line 23

Comment: Arrglado, delete the variable before time, THANK YOU